# Really new to Vue , can you help me with a sum?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

thanks for anybody reading me here ,
I have got this code from my prof and I want ,need to calculate automatically the sum , the total of the players in the html I mean being displayed.
I'm really new to this , can anybody help me out ?
Want to understand The Vue.js math functions in order to progress in my studies and in math as well.
Last..so full of doubt here , sorry guys , Vue.js is a js library ..so I cannot put a js script inside vue.js right ?

Thanks

```
var players = [
  { label: 'A', value: 100 },
  { label: 'B', value: 100 },
  { label: 'C', value: 100 },
  { label: 'D', value: 100 },
  { label: 'E', value: 100 },
  { label: 'F', value: 100 }
]

Vue.component("polygraph", {
    template: "#polygraphComponent",
    props: ["stats", "width"],
    computed: {
        radius() { return (this.width / 2); },
        viewbox() {
            var size = this.width;
            var min = -(size / 2);
            return [min, min, size, size].join(" ");
        },
        points() {
            var total = this.stats.length
            return this.stats.map((stat, i) => {
                var point = valueToPoint(stat.value, i, total)
                return point.x + "," + point.y
            }).join(" ")
        }
    },
    components: {
        axisLabel: {
            template: "#axisLabelComponent",
            props: {
                stat: Object,
                index: Number,
                total: Number
            },
            computed: {
                point() {
                    return valueToPoint(
                        this.stat.value,
                        this.index,
                        this.total
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        newLabel: "",
        players: players,
        width: 600
    },
    methods: {
        add(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault()
            if (!this.newLabel) return
            this.players.push({
                label: this.newLabel,
                value: 100
            })
            this.newLabel = ""
        },
        remove(stat) {
            if (this.players.length > 3) {
                this.players.$remove(stat)
            } else {
                alert("Can't remove more!")
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
        scoreControl: {
            template: "#scoreControlComponent",
            props: {
                stat: Object,
                index: Number,
                total: Number
            },
            computed: {
                point() {
                    return valueToPoint(
                        this.stat.value,
                        this.index,
                        this.total
                    )
                },
                style() {
                    var angle = this.point.angle;
                    return {
                        transform: "rotate(" + angle + "rad)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

// math helper...
function valueToPoint(value, index, total) {
  var maxV  = 100
  var maxR  = 300 * 0.9
  var r     = maxR / maxV * value
  var angle = Math.PI * 2 / total * index + Math.PI / 2
  var cos   = Math.cos(angle)
  var sin   = Math.sin(angle)
  var tx    = r * cos
  var ty    = r * sin
  return {
    angle: angle,
    radius: r,
    x: tx,
    y: ty
  }
}
```

Comment: "so I cannot put a js script inside vue.js right" not sure what that means; You certainly don't want to put a method inside the vue.js "source", but you have your own app and component that can take methods where you can put your `valueToPoint` into like you did with `point()` and `style()`

Comment: Vue has NO math functions. If you have problems with math part of the code, it's pure JS.